# Phonegap non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am getting this error in my phonegap:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)­navigationType
```

The error appears to be right after the ")" from "(UIWebViewNavigationType)­". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an invisible "Soft hyphen" (U+00AD) character between "(UIWebViewNavigationType)" and "navigationType". Removing that character should fix the problem.

Comment: Wow thank you that helped! I really didn't expect that because I pasted this code from somewhere and Objective C is not my language.

Comment: @SinanSamet: You are welcome. - If you have completely strange compiler errors then it sometimes helps to activate the "Show Invisibles" option, which is available in Xcode and many other editors.